# Why would child_process exit before child_process.stdout emits 'end'?

Tags: node.js

I'm seeing cases where a child process exits with return code 0 even though the stdout hasn't emitted `'end'` yet. How/why would this happen?

It breaks my mental model, since I thought that when a process exits it gives up its resources, including stdio.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
// ...
const child = spawn(theBinary, args, spawnOptions);
child.stdout.on('end', () => console.log('stdout ends'));
child.on('exit', (code) => console.log(`exited with code ${code}`); // sometimes this happens without stdout ending
```

Comment: I mean, `stdout` is a stream and `child` is a process. I don't see why this is that surprising. When the stream has reached its end `end` is emitted: _The 'end' event is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed from the stream._ but that is obviously independent of the process that was spawned. It even makes more sense in that order, because in order for the stdout stream to truly be "empty" the process has to exit first (i.e. cannot produce anymore data to be consumed)